# Sort File Names, Group by ID and Sort by Date/Time

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the below list of file names and I want to group by the ID and sort DESC or ASC by the datetime string as well.

I've done this in Python using a lambda function but haven't a clue where to start in javascript, any help appreciated?

File format: `{Type}_{ID}_{Descriptor}_{Datetime}.{Extension}`

```
site_732_i_202012120010.xml
site_733_i_202012120010.json
site_723_i_202012140301.xml
site_832_f_202012140301.json
```

My code so far:

```
for (var key in data) {
    count = 0;
    
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        tabs += "<li><a id=\"tab_" + key + "\">Location " + key + " (<span id=\"tab_" + key + "_count\">%%</span>)</a></li>";
        
        tabData += "<div class=\"tabContainer\" id=\"tab_" + key + "C\">";
        
        tabData += "<div class\"pending\"><h3>Pending</h3>";
        
        // Pending Files
        for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(data[key]['pending']).sort()) {
            tabData += "<div>" + v + "</div>";
            count++;
        }
        
        tabData += "</div><div class\"archived\"><h3>Archived</h3>";
        
        // Archived Files
        for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(data[key]['archived']).sort()) {
            tabData += "<div>" + v + "</div>";
        }
        
        tabData += "</div>";
        
        tabs = tabs.replace("%%", count);
        
        tabData += "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: With ~2.5k rep you must surely know that you're expected to demonstrate effort.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what is your expectation?

Comment: Yeah it does appear to be an easy problem. What I would need to know is, are the filenames in an array? And if so, where is that code? The array declaration even, would suffice.

Comment: @Mitya Sorry, cut/pasted the wrong copy of question from notepad, updated now.

Comment: Downvote/close vote retracted.